# Sending multiple API request using Promise

Tags: javascript, ajax, promise, async-await

How to send multiple API request? so I have this code below

```
 const productID= [12, 43, 65, 87, 45, 76, 87];
    productID.map(id => {
     API.removeItem(id, (err, response) => {
       if (response.status === 'success') {
           console.log('remove a product');
        }else {
          console.log(err); 
        }
     })
})
```

The problem is that it doesn't wait for first API request to finish and get the response back, and only removing one item. So basically I wanted this to become synchronous and that's why I use async await to resolve my problem.

```
async function removeProducts() {
    const productID = [12, 43, 65, 87, 45, 76, 87];
    const result = await Promise.all(productID.map(id => {
        API.removeItem(id, (err, response) => {
            if (response.status === 'success') {
                console.log('remove a product');
            }else {
                console.log(err); 
        }
        });
    }));
}
```

The result of this is almost the same as the first code snippet, but it this time it was able to remove 2 product items. I want that the next request is made only if  the previous request is finished. How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make all AJAX calls sequential?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151598/how-to-make-all-ajax-calls-sequential)

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your second attempt is that `Promise.all()` takes an array of promises as an argument.  The `Promise.all()` function also returns a promise itself that is resolved when every promise in the array passed in is resolved.

The `array.map` does not return a promise, it returns a new array with the results of every item in the array called with the provided function.  Read more about the map function [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Instead create a wrapper function for the API call that returns a promise.

```
const productID = [12, 43, 65, 87, 45, 76, 87];

let removeProductID = (id) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        API.removeItem(id, (err, response) => {
            if (response.status === 'success') {
                console.log('remove a product');
                resolve(response);
            } else {
                console.log(err);
                reject(err);
            }
        })
    });
}

let removeAllProductIDs = async () => {
    for(let id of productID) {
        await removeProductID(id);
    }
}

removeAllProductIDs();
```

Answer (score 1):

> Actually **Promise.All()** make the parallel request so this is not a solution that you are looking for.
>
> What you need is that **yield** the result then make another request and so on. For that, you need **API.removeItem** to return **Promise**.if it is not then you can wrap this function using Promise API to return Promise.

```
    async function removeItem(id) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        API.removeItem(id, (err, response) => {
          if (response.status === 'success') {
            resolve("message or data"); // or pass id or anything
          } else {
            console.log(err);
            reject(err)
          }
        })
      })
    }
```

> Now you can use this function to yield the result.

```
 const productID = [12, 43, 65, 87, 45, 76, 87];
    async function removeProducts() {
       for (let i = 0; i < productID.length; i++) {
            const result = await removeItem(productID[i]); // will return resolved value here
            // sequence
          }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const productID = [12, 43, 65, 87, 45, 76, 87];
function process() {
    if (productID.length == 0) return;

    var id = productID.pop();
    API.removeItem(id, (err, response) => {
       if (response.status === 'success') {
           console.log('remove a product');
           process(); // process next item if success
        } else {
          console.log(err); 
        }
    });
};

process();
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the other answers, start by promisifying `API.removeItem` (If your environment is Node.js, you can use [`util.promisify`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original), otherwise use the `Promise` constructor as shown in other answers):

```js
const {promisify} = require('util');

const removeItem = promisify(API.removeItem);
```

Then, if you don't mind pulling in a third party module, you can use [`async-af`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-af) (a module I maintain) to loop through the IDs sequentially using an [async forEach](https://async-af.js.org/AsyncAF#forEachAF):

```js
const AsyncAF = require('async-af');

const removeItems = ids => AsyncAF(ids).series.forEach(removeItem);

removeItems([12, 43, 65, 87, 45, 76, 87]);
```

Alternatively, you can use vanilla JS to loop through the ids sequentially; for instance, here's an implementation using `Array.prototype.reduce`:

```js
const removeItems = ids => ids.reduce((acc, id) => (
  acc.then(() => removeItem(id))
), Promise.resolve());

removeItems([12, 43, 65, 87, 45, 76, 87]);
```