Question about synchronous ajax call in JS
With below code, what I was expecting is "diameter-selected" class to be added to the button and then to run the synchronous ajax calls. But, it seems that ajax calls run before the ".addClass" command and since it is waiting the promise I guess, I see the button effect after ajax request is completed. When I added setTimeout to the ajax calls for 1 nano second, I see the button effect before ajax calls are completed. So, I solved my issue in a weird way but I want to learn if there is a more professional way to achieve this.
    $(document).on("click", ".btn-diameter", function(){

       $(this).addClass("diameter-selected");

       $.ajax({
         method: "POST",
         async: false,
         url: "/page1.asp"
       });

       $.ajax({
         method: "POST",
         async: false,
         url: "/page2.asp"
       });

    });     


The class is added first, but the browser doesn't re-render the UI because the thread is blocked by synchronous operations.  The way to solve this is to remove async: false, which shouldn't be used anyway.  (Which is deprecated since jQuery 1.8)

"I want to learn if there is a more professional way to achieve this" - just stop using async: false already!

Just a note: "Synchronous XHR is now deprecated and should be avoided in favor of asynchronous requests." ,  IOW:  Even if this works now, there is a good chance it will fail next time you upgrade your browser.

if you want to make sequential AJAX requests, do the second request in the success: function of the first one. Or use async and await.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151598/how-to-make-all-ajax-calls-sequential

Yes, putting second request to success callback worked much better. It didn't block rendering and I achieved what I want to do. Thanks to all guys commented!

This is because your requests with async: false block main browser's thread. That's why it won't re-render an element with a new css class until your synchronical requests are fulfilled.
So, just replace your code with this (in order to save synchronicity you should use success callback):
  $(document).on("click", ".btn-diameter", function(){

    $(this).addClass("diameter-selected");
    
    
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/page1.asp",
        success: function() {
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "/page2.asp"
            });
        }
    });
    
}); 

Btw I use success instead of done, according to jquery docs (https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false with jqXHR ($.Deferred) is deprecated; you must use the success/error/complete callback options instead of the corresponding methods of the jqXHR object such as jqXHR.done()

However, it is better to use Promises instead like this:
$(document).on("click", ".btn-diameter", function(){
    $(this).addClass("diameter-selected");
    fetch("/page1.asp", { method: "POST" })
        .then(() => fetch("/page2.asp", { method: "POST" }))
}); 


Please, add second request into the other's done callback and I will mark your answer as accepted solution. Because, it should be working synchronously. That is why I set it to async: true in the first place. (I couldn't edit your answer)

@UgurCatak thank you for your adjustments. I've updated my answer. Due to recommendations from jquery documentation I use success instead of done



var myajax = (url,method)=>{
  var dfrd = $.Deferred();
  $.ajax({
    url,
    method,
    success:dfrd.resolve,
        error:dfrd.rejected
  });
  return dfrd.promise();
};
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
  myajax('path-to-post-1','post').then((response1)=>{
    console.log(response1);
    return myajax('path-to-post-2','post');
  }).then(response2=>{
    console.log(response2);
    return myajax('path-to-post-3','post');
  }).then(response3=>{
    return myajax('path-to-post-4','post');
  }).fail(err=>console.log('Ada Error: ',err));
});
</script>



